# Create Multiple Jabber Client Echo Bot

Tags: node.js, typescript, xmpp, node-xmpp

**Hai Stackoverflowers,**
i had try so many ways to fix my problem and i end up with stack over flow

**Programming Language:** 
Typescript

**my main goals:**
create Client Class as many as i want and can turn on and turn off the Client, the client will be as Bot that echo text from the friendlist

I use node-xmpp-client Library :
https://github.com/chris-rock/node-xmpp-client

**My Code :**

```
import * as Client from 'node-xmpp-client'; // Jabber Helper

export class TerminalJabber {
  private ter;
  private client;

  constructor(ter: any) {
    this.ter = ter;
    this.client = new Client({
      jid: this.ter.settings.username,
      password: this.ter.settings.password,
    });
  }

  public turnOn(){
    // Turn on Jabber
    this.client.on('online', () => {
      console.log('online');
      const stanza = new Client.Element('presence', { })
         .c('show').t('chat').up()
         .c('status').t('Happily echoing your <message/> stanzas');
      this.client.send(stanza);
    });

    this.client.on('stanza', (stanza) => {
      // Message come here and will echo from here
    });

     // Catch error
     this.client.on('error', (e) => {
       console.log('------>', e);
     });
  }
  // Turn Off Jabber
  public turnOff () {
    // Turn Off Jabber
    this.client.end();
    return true;
  }
}
```

**The Problem is,** The Bot Can Start, but never will be disconnect when i call a new class and **turnOn()** and **turnOff().**

How I call My code:
      // Hit URL
      /turnOn/:terId

```
// Hit URL
app.router.get(/turnOn/:id, turnOnController); // for turn On
app.router.get(/turnOff/:id, turnOfController); // for turn Off

TurnOnController(){
  // Get data from database using id
  const data = Query ~ ;
  const terminal = new TerminalId(data)
  terminal.turnOn();
}

TurnOffController(){
// Get data from database using id
  const data = Query ~ ;
  const terminal = new TerminalID(data)
  terminal.turnOff();
}
```

Maybe you have a solution of my problems ?
have been thinking and read so many post about xmpp, but i cant solve this things,

Please help

sincerely,
Thank you

Comment: You may want to add the code where you use this class and show how you connect and disconnect etc.

Comment: just like this :
ter is Object data that store credentials
const temp = new TerminalJabber (ter);
temp.turnOn();

and after 1 day or 2 days, i want to turn off this Bot
just hit the url that trigger 

const temp = new TerminalJabber (ter);
temp.turnOff();

and when i hit and turnon url i can turn on Jabber Bot with their credential..

Comment: Please add the code to your question above. (Use the edit link bellow your question) You need to call the turnOff function on the temp instance before you create a new one.

Comment: @Molda Done sir, please take a look..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the turnOff method on the `terminal` instance before you create new one.
This also means you need to have access to the instance from both controllers.

```
var terminals = {};

function turnOnController(){

    var id = getIdSomehow();

    terminal[id] = new TerminalId(data);
    terminal[id].turnOn();

}

function turnOffController(){

    var id = getIdSomehow();

    if (terminal[id])
        terminal[id].turnOff();

}
```

Comment: But, is that ok ? 
if on my terminal class i declare New Client ? the data will be affected or not ?

because when i trigger the TurnOn, my console will be idle because of even listener..

and imagine if i have 100 Id, so i have 100 client idle for this XMPP Bot center..
so by doing your answer, is that can turn off which bot if they triggered ?

By the way, if it's oke if i use let instead of var ? because i use typescript that not allowed for var..

Comment: If you initialize the instances with `new TerminalId` the data will be unique to each instance. They will not affect each other. I don't use typescript so can't help you with the *let* or *var* thing. Also the number of the clients you can create will probably depend on your system.

Comment: So if i dont want to change the instances, should i save the **New TerminalId** to my Db ? so in next time when i want to turn off, i just call from my DB,

because when we turn on it, and another user will turn on it also right ? so i am not sure the instances will be same, how do you thing about that ?

your answer help me alot btw.
Thanks alot, and i think i need a little more bit discuss with you to open up my mind

Comment: You can't save an instance to the DB. You can save its id to db if that helps. You could check if the instance with the given id already exists and create new one only if it doesn't. Once you turn it off you could also delete it from instances. Something like `delete terminals[id]`

Comment: Thank you @Molda you help me a lot to solve my problem, because i still new on Node JS so i need to learn from the expert like you,

By the way, how i get the return value from the listener as you see from my terminal Class, instead of using var, in node Js have another way to get the return value from event listener ?

i have try so many suggestion from stack overflow, but i cant find the suit one, or maybe i dont understand ..